# Numpy Deep Copy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having some trouble copying an array using numpy. I'm running a few different sort functions and comparing run times, so I need a copy of the original array and one I modify. Here's the code I've got.

```
import numpy
import random

SIZE = 10
DISPLAY = True

def random_fill():
    return numpy.array([random.random()*10000 for i in range(SIZE)])

def copy(p):
    return numpy.copy(p)

def display(p):
    if (DISPLAY):
        print a
        print

def bubble_sort(array):
    temp = 0
    for i in range(SIZE, 1, -1):
        for j in range(1, i):
            if (array[j-1] > array[j]):
                temp = array[j-1]
                array[j-1] = array[j]
                array[j] = temp

a = random_fill()
b = copy(a)
display(a)
display(b)
bubble_sort(a)
display(a)
display(b)
```

First `a` and `b` display properly, being a random array. Then `a` sorts and displays correctly but `b` displays exactly what `a` is. `b` should remain unsorted. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `print a` but `print p` otherwise you print the global array instead of the one passed to the function.